# Is n-Step SARSA Off-Policy?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

To keep things simple, let us consider the case of an episodic Finite MDP with n=2 and no discounts. Copying the equation for n-step SARSA from Reinforcement Learning 2nd edition, page 146:

The n-step update rule would be:[image]
Translating this to our case for n=2, the 2-step update rule would be:
$$Q_{t+2}(S_t,A_t) =Q_{t+1}(S_t,A_t) +\alpha[R_{t+1} + R_{t+2} + Q_{t+1}(S_{t+2},A_{t+2}) -Q_{t+1}(S_t,A_t)  ]   $$
Let us simulate the algorithm:

- t=0 : Take action $A_0$  based on $Q_1$, get reward $R_1$. Pick the next action $A_1$ based on $Q_1$
- t=1: Take action $A_1(Q_1)$, get reward $R_2$. Pick the next action $A_2$, based on $Q_1$.
  We then update $Q_1 -> Q_2$
- t=2: Take action $A_2(Q_1)$, get reward $R_3$. Pick the next action $A_3$, based on $Q_2$.
  We then update $Q_2 -> Q_3$
- t=3: Take action $A_3(Q_2)$, get reward $R_4$. Pick the next action $A_4$, based on $Q_3$.
  We then update $Q_3 -> Q_4$
- ….

$Q_3(S_1,A_1) =Q_2(S_1,A_1) +\alpha.[R_2 + R_3 + Q_2(S_3,A_3) -Q_2(S_1,A_1)  ]$

Consider above equation. We are constructing a boot-strapped estimate for $Q_2(S_1,A_1)$. This is the value that would accrue if we took action $A_1$ in $S_1$ and then followed policy encoded in $Q_2$ after that.

- $R_2$ consequence of playing $A_1$ . Note that since we are learning action value function, $A_1$ need not be "on-policy".
- $R_3$ consequence of playing $A_2$ which is picked based on the policy encoded by $Q_1$ not $Q_2$ . **This seems off-policy**.
- $Q_2(S_3,A_3)$ - $A_3$ is picked based on policy encoded by $Q_2$

It seems to be that we need to do an off-policy correction for $R_3$ which results from $A_2$ based on $Q_1$. Would love feedback on this.

Comment: The $Q$ functions are only updated *after* taking the $n$ steps, not after each individual step -- I think this should clear up your confusion.